# How to print in REPL the code of functions in Julia?

Tags: julia, introspection

In Julia, a lot of the Base and closer related functions are also written in pure Julia, and the code is easily avaible. One can skim through the repository or the local downloaded files, and see how the function is written/implemented. But I think there is allready some built in method that does that for you, so you can write in REPL or Jupyter Notebook something like:

```
@code functioninquestion()
```

and get something like:

```
functioninquestion(input::Type)
   some calculations
   return
end
```

without pagingh throug the code.

I just don't remember the method or call. I have read the Reflection/Introspection section of the Manual but I cannot seem to be able to use anything there. I've tried `methods`, `methodswith`, `code_lowered`, `expand` and cannot seem to make them give what I want-

Comment: It is very nice to have the people at Julia development directly answering the questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though this may not be what the OP is looking for, `@less` is very convenient to read the underlying code (so I very often use it). For example,

```
julia> @less 1 + 2
```

gives

```
+(x::Int, y::Int) = box(Int,add_int(unbox(Int,x),unbox(Int,y)))
```

which corresponds to the line given by

```
julia> @which 1 + 2
+(x::Int64, y::Int64) at int.jl:8
```

Comment: Well I tried `@less shuffle!()` but it doesn't work.... but if I give to `shuffle!` an argument then  it works, so it sorta works... although it goes some lines below the code.  Thanks!

Comment: @wpkzz `@less shuffle!()` naturally doesn't work because you are then asking to look at the method which responds to a shuffle function call with no arguments. That does not exist, so you get nothing. You got to give it an actual argument like `@less shuffle!([1, 2])`. Remember in Julia each function has multiple method implementation depending on arguments passed. Julia need to know your argument to pick the method to show you.

Answer (score 9):

This is not currently supported but probably will be in the future.

Comment: This is technically correct.  `@edit` and `@less` rely upon the backtrace information in the function and just point to the file in which they were defined.  This doesn't work, of course, if the function was defined in a Jupyter notebook or the REPL.  Or it may display stale code that's been changed since Julia loaded it.  Not sure why the downvote here.

Comment: The OP had asked about looking at code in Base, and Stefan's response didn't answer that.  Bringing up the issue of code defined in a Jupyter notebook or the REPL, or that might be stale, *is* a useful addition to the other answers, even though it may not be relevant for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

`@edit functioninquestion()` will open up your editor to the location of the method given.
It probably wouldn't be to hard to take the same information used by `@edit` and use it to open the file and skip to the method definition, and then display it directly in the REPL (or Jupyter).
EDIT: While I was answering, somebody else mentioned `@less`, which seems to do exactly what you want already.

Answer (score 1):

There is now another tool for this, https://github.com/timholy/CodeTracking.jl. It is part of Revise.jl (and works better when also using Revise). It should work inside Jupyter and with functions defined in the REPL, unlike @edit/@less.

Comment: CodeTracking.jl does work with REPL, but I couldn't get it working in Jupyter. It only prints `nothing` when `@code_string` is called with a function defined immediately above.