# Show function source code from repl

Tags: julia

I would like to view the definition of a method in REPL. I follow this link (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2625) but it doesn't work:

```
julia> f(x) = x^2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> expand(f)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(f)
# 1 method for generic function "f":
f(x) at REPL[155]:1

julia> implementation(f,1)
ERROR: UndefVarError: implementation not defined
 in eval_user_input(::Any, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackend) at ./REPL.jl:64
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:95 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##3#4{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:68
```

It seems that the method `implementation` doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean for a method you have also defined in the REPL? Because if the method is defined in a file, you can use `@less`, at least on unix/osx.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a direct way isn't implemented yet.

Here's one of the creators saying so 6 months ago - doesn't seem to have been made, as there are a few duplicate issues of this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662987/7754070